# Burning smell from RAM

Tags: memory, ddr3

i just installed a new RAM by replacing the old one . both are same specification,but only increase in size of the RAM .

here the spec of my old ram

- 2 GB DDR3
- 1600 mhz
- 1.35v low voltage
- latency 11

new ram

spec is same

- 4 GB
  here the [link](https://www.amazon.in/Transcend-4GB-DDR3L-1600-LAPTOP/dp/B00B5LOOJG)

and it is so hot  5mins after system boots up

should i worry about this?

will it cost any damage to RAM or motherboard like short circuit?

P.S : i found all he specs using cpu-z.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. Thank you for sharing your message. Is there an actual question attached here? If so, what is the question? Currently its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @LPChip now i added my question

Comment: How do you know its the Ram that is burning. Where any ram slots previously empty before your upgrade?

Comment: @Dave no i have only one ram slot.according to OS and manufacture there is another slot (may be it was dummied).you know its the Ram that is burning? i can smell from the RAm opening in panel

Comment: So yoiu know it's the RAM, not the slot? Or the board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the specifications are really the same - and that's an issue: I found a mislabeled RAM once, the seller had placed it back in the wrong sleeve - and the motherboard is rated for that size of RAM (it should), then you've nothing to fear.

Just in case, verify that the contacts are good - a **soft** pencil eraser is handy for cleaning RAM contacts. It's unlikely to be an issue because the RAM shouldn't even *work* if it was. Dust accurately the sticks and the slots using canned air or a vacuum cleaner (watch it, I once vacuumed a jumper off; luckily I heard it rattle on the way in :-) ).

Sometimes RAMs are coated in a thin protective slippery film of something that gives off that smell when heated. I noticed this with some Hynix sticks (*possibly it's there to keep contacts from oxidising in storage, even if AFAIK they're gold-plated and so shouldn't*). You can clean them with isopropyl alcohol. Needless to say, never use water :-).

To keep RAM temperature monitored, if supported by BIOS and motherboard, there are tools like Almico's SpeedFan. I think it has an option for emergency shutdown in case of overheating; you need to set the warning thresholds.

**UPDATE**: you may also want to look into a [RAM heatsink](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/ram-heatsink). They're basically copper or copper-plated aluminum shims that clamp on the RAM and spread the heat evenly, and/or increase the heat exchanging surfaces. If the worst comes to the worst, there are even active RAM coolers (e.g. [this one from Thermaltake](https://www.ebay.com/p/Thermaltake-V1r-Cl-r0029-RAM-Memory-Cooler-Heatsink/1566580844?iid=112608599884)).

Comment: can you provide the link to Almico's speed fan software (secure site)

Comment: If you mean HTTPS, there is no secure site. The official site is http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php .

Comment: what if my processor heats up ? my processor is .AMD A4-4300 APU  2.50Ghz. but that still exists cleaned dust tried re inserting too

Comment: You ought to check the heatsink is properly seated and pasted using the thinnest possible layer of thermal grease.

Comment: what is that ()heatsink

Answer (score 0):

Before you close the case you should vacuum out as much dust as possible and even use a can of compressed air on the fans and the power supply. Then you should close the case. The fans won’t work efficiently if the case is open.

Comment: so ,i dont have to worry thank you for you answer. it won't affect my RAM ?